JHipster 8.4.0 Kubernetes Generator Issue
JHipster version: 8.4.0
Node version: v20.12.2
Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?
Error Details: JHipster 8.4.0 Kubernetes Generator Failed while running jhipster:docker-compose#writeKeycloakFiles: ERROR! An error occured while running jhipster:docker-compose#writeKeycloakFiles ERROR! ERROR! C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\dist\generators\docker-compose\templates\realm-config\jhipster-realm.json.ejs:550 548|       "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false, 549|       "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",

550|       "secret": "<%= keycloakSecrets[0] %>", 551|       "redirectUris": [ 552|         "/realms/jhipster/account/*" 553|       ],

keycloakSecrets is not defined ReferenceError: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\dist\generators\docker-compose\templates\realm-config\jhipster-realm.json.ejs:550 548|       "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false, 549|       "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",

550|       "secret": "<%= keycloakSecrets[0] %>", 551|       "redirectUris": [ 552|         "/realms/jhipster/account/*" 553|       ],

keycloakSecrets is not defined at DockerComposeGenerator.eval ("C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\dist\generators\docker-compose\templates\realm-config\jhipster-realm.json.ejs":24:26) at jhipster-realm.json (C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17) at exports.render (C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:425:37) at render (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/util.js:62:16) at MemFsEditor._processTpl (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/actions/copy-tpl.js:6:12) at process (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/actions/copy-tpl.js:19:47) at applyProcessingFunc (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/actions/copy.js:9:20) at MemFsEditor._copySingle (file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/actions/copy.js:63:20) at file:///C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/dist/actions/copy.js:52:14 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) { path: 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\dist\generators\docker-compose\templates\realm-config\jhipster-realm.json.ejs' }

1. Install jhipster 8.4.0
2. Run jhipster jdl <filename>.jdl

Kubernetes Deployment confioguration in jdl:
deployment {
  deploymentType kubernetes
  appsFolders [service1, service12]
  monitoring prometheus
  serviceDiscoveryType consul
  kubernetesNamespace msns
  kubernetesServiceType LoadBalancer
}

